# Why OpenCV HSV blue is green?

Tags: python, opencv, colors

I am trying to convert blue from BGR to HSV using OpenCV. My code is:

```py
blue = np.uint8([[[255,0,0 ]]]) 
hsv_blue = cv2.cvtColor(blue, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) 
lo_square = np.full((10, 10, 3), hsv_blue, dtype=np.uint8) / 255.0

plt.subplot(1, 1, 1) 
plt.imshow(hsv_to_rgb(lo_square))
plt.show()
```

And color that I am getting looks like this:

[image: Plotted generated image]

Why green value is 1? Where did opencv get it from? (Note that the converted colour value is visible in the graphic, `[0, 1, 0.824]` and the value of `hsv_blue` is `array([[[120, 255, 255]]], dtype=uint8)`)

Comment: What is the value of `hsv_blue`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `dtype` `uint8`, `h` assumes values between 0 and 180 when using `cv2.cvtColor(blue, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)`, so you should divide it by `180.`, not `255.`, even though the s and v values are in 0 .. 255 ranges.

This works:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import hsv_to_rgb
from cv2 import cv2

blue = np.uint8([[[255, 0, 0]]])
hsv_blue = cv2.cvtColor(blue, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lo_square = np.full((10, 10, 3), hsv_blue, dtype=np.uint8) / [180., 255., 255.]

plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.imshow(hsv_to_rgb(lo_square))
plt.show()
```